# How do I add a BackgroundImage to a ListView in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-image

I am aware that there is no property called `BackgroundImage` for the ListView class - only the `BackgroundColor` property but that is not what I am looking for. Is there a way to add a background image to the ListView so that when I scroll the image stays in place and the tiles simply 'move' over the image as you scroll.

Adding the image to the `ContentPage` also does not work since the ListView simply overlays it.

Comment: You could try making the background of the list view and list view items transparent and putting the image behind the list view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post is really good, you just miss a doble quotations marks on the Source property

Set your `ListView`'s `BackgroundColor` to `Transparent`:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Image Source="background.png" 
        BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" 
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"
              ItemsSource="{Binding .}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @LeMotJuiced Setting the background color should have no effect on a ListView scrolling, you should post a new question with your issue and code

Comment: It's not setting the background color, it's putting a ListView inside RelativeLayout.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced The question is concerning a background image, I have used RelativeLayouts and they have been fine, it depends upon the container, etc... you should post a new question with your issue and code

Comment: For the moment I'm just scrapping the whole idea. I just posted the comment in case you knew a quick fix. I upvoted you, dude, don't harsh on me!